# Converting String to DateTime format in MongoDB to support time based query

Tags: java, mongodb

So far I am converting received date time value (e.g. 2023-06-27T16:57:18.894Z) as String using jackson parser. And saving in MongoDB as String all the way. Now I am trying to store it as date time in MongoDB to be able to do time based query.

I updated by jackson converter field as

```
@JsonProperty
@JsonFormat (shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.SSSZ)
private String eventDateTime
```

MongoDb Entity

```
@Document("event")
class EventEntity {
  private ZonedDateTime eventDateTime;
  ...
}
```

Converting String to ZonedDateTime

```
eventEntity.setEventDateTime(ZonedDateTime.parse(event.getEventDateTime(), DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME));
```

Exception

```
Caused by: org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class java.time.ZonedDateTime
```

Do I need to write codec? There should be easy way to convert string time stamp to MongoDB Date type. Any suggestion?